# Locating a file without knowing its name, only its content?

Tags: files, search

I have a hard drive filled with files, and I need to find a specific file without knowing its name. All I know is that the file contains a list of email addresses. Is there any way I can locate it?

Comment: GUI or cli? both are in the dupes above :)

Answer (score 1):

Via `find` and `grep`

I don't use `grep -r` because in POSIX systems, you don't find `-r` parameter for `grep`.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'your_email_address' {} \;
```

Or

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l -- 'your_email_address' +
```

There are many possibilities.

The command finds all files in the current folder and subfolders and passes the result to `grep`. `grep` finds the files with `your_email_address`.

Comment: Why not just `grep -r 'your_email_address'`?

Comment: Hmm, I'm a friend of `find` =)

Comment: In its present state, this will not give the name of the file that contains the match. It will only give the match.

Comment: Sorry, corrected

Comment: @saiarcot895 And in POSIX systems, you don't find -r parameter for grep.

Comment: @A.B. if you like `find`, why not just use `grep -l` with it? e.g. `find . -type f -exec grep -l -- 'email_address' {} +`

Comment: @A.B. since grep can take multiple files on the command line, `{} +` should be more efficient than `{} \;` in the second command. In your first command, `\;` seems superfluous since `{}` is an argument to `xargs`, not `find -exec`.

Comment: @steeldriverb thank you again, in on mobile and in a train it's hard to change answers. :) I was always in the `xargs` mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `grep -r`:

Here is an example where I grepped for the text "listen_address" in any file from my home dir:

```
aploetz@dockingBay94:~$ grep -r listen_address *
Documents/stackOverFlowAnswer_connectToCassandra.txt~:If you are connecting to Cassandra from your localhost only (a sandbox machine), then you can set the `listen_address` in your cassandra.yaml:
Documents/stackOverFlowAnswer_connectToCassandra.txt~:    listen_address: localhost
Documents/stackOverFlowAnswer_connectToCassandra.txt:If you are connecting to Cassandra from your localhost only (a sandbox machine), then you can set the `listen_address` in your cassandra.yaml:
Documents/stackOverFlowAnswer_connectToCassandra.txt:    listen_address: localhost
Documents/stackOverFlowAnswer_connectToCassandra.txt:    listen_address: dockingBay94
Ubuntu One/cassandraClass/cassandra.yaml:listen_address: $(HOSTNAME)
Ubuntu One/cassandraClass/cassandra.yaml:# Leaving this blank will set it to the same value as listen_address
```

Comment: You don't need the asterix :)

Comment: Adding the -l option means you'll just get the filename, without listing the file contents.